# How to change the fontsize in beamer_presentation smaller?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, font-size

I want to make the font size of code Chunk in R markdown smaller so that each slide can contain more content.

I tried to set the font size for the total beamer,

```
title: "In"
author: "Y"
output: beamer_presentation
font_adjustment: -2
```

But even I changed "font_adjustment = -2 " to "-15", there seems no changes to the font size.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer,

```
fontsize:  12 pt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you put it?

Comment: Somewhere to the end of the YAML-header (on the top level, so not subordinate to e.g. `output: beamer_presentation`)